# How do I configure SpeechSynthesizer to use phonetics so that it can read proper nouns (names)?

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis, phonetics

I am using SpeechSynthesizer and I wanted to configure it to use phonetics so I don't have to add individual lexicons. End result expected would be that if I passed it a proper noun it shouldn't read it out and not spell it out.

My current code is as follows

```
    public void ReadWord(string word)
    {
        using (SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
        {   
            synth.Speak(word);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try hunting around [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378516%28v=office.14%29.aspx).